# Clojure `defn` parameter in parentheses or not

Tags: clojure

I saw a Clojure function is defined as

```
(defn toInt([i] (Integer. i)))
```

why the parameter `[i]` is included in parentheses? is this the same as below? any differences?

```
 (defn toInt [i] (Integer. i))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first uses the notation for arity overloading, but contains only one arity.

Example with two arities:

```
(defn my-add 
  ([x] (+ x 1))
  ([x y] (+ x y)))

(my-add 1) ;;=> 2
(my-add 1 2) ;;=> 3
```

Also see http://clojure.org/functional_programming (search for arity overloading).